# Python how to parse 2 URLs from a string and then map it back?

Tags: python, urllib

I have a column in a pandas dataframe where some of the values are in this format: "From https://....com?gclid=... to https://...com". What I would like is to parse only the first URL so that the gclid and other IDs would vanish and I would like to map back that into the dataframe e.g.: "From https://....com to https://...com"

I know that there is a python module called urllib but if I apply that to this string a call a path() on it, it just parses the first URL and then I lose the other part which is as important as the first one.

Could somebody please help me? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking. Can you post some code showing the specific behavior you want?

Comment: if you has so simple string `"From https://....com to https://...com"` then you can `text.replace("From ", "").replace(" to ", ' ').split(" ")` to get list `["https://....com", "https://...com"]`

Comment: if I do this: t = urllib.parse.urlparse("From https:///?gclid=... to https://"), this is what I get back: ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='From https://', params='', query='gclid=.. to https://', fragment=''). My problem is that the second URL is going to the query part so if I call t.path(), I get back only the From https:// part, instead of the first URL parsed and the second URL as well (I would like to delete the ID and other unique identifiers from the first URL and then map it back in the place of the original value

Comment: if you want to remove `?gclid= ...` then you try to use regex to replace it.

Comment: if you will have list `["https://....com?gclid=", "https://...com"]` then you can get first element from list and `split('?')` to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use DataFrame then use `replace()` which can use regex to find text like `"?.... "`  (which starts with `?` and ends with `space` - or which starts with `?` and have only chars different then `space` - `'\?[^ ]+'`)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["From https://....com?gclid=... to https://...com"]})

df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('\?[^ ]+', '')
```

Result

```
                                     text
0  From https://....com to https://...com
```

---

**BTW:** you can also try more complex regex to make sure it is part of url which starts with `http`.

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('(http[^?]+)\?[^ ]+', '\\1')
```

I use `(...)` to catch this url before `?...` and I put it back using `\\1` (already without `?...`)

Comment: wow, thank you, the BTW part was exactly what I needed! Have a nice day kind Stranger!